# Inputing date on react-day-picker input formatted with date-fns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-day-picker, date-fns

I can't type the date manually with react-day-picker using `onDayChange` but I can when I use an `onChange`. However, I do not get the selected value with an `onChange` and also I am using date-fns to format the date.

```
handleChangeDate(date, value) {
    this.setState({
      [value]: date,
    });
  }

  parseDate(str, format, locale) {
    const parsed = dateFnsParse(str, format, new Date(), { locale });

    if (dateFnsValid(parsed)) {
      return parsed;
    }

    return undefined;
  }

  formatDate(date, format, locale) {
    return dateFnsFormat(date, format, { locale });
  }
```

Using onDayChange

```
<DayPickerInput
   placeholder="Date Engaged"
   value={dateEngaged}
   format="dd/MM/yyyy"
   formatDate={this.formatDate}
   parseDate={this.parseDate}
   onDayChange={value => this.handleChangeDate(value, 'dateEngaged')}
  />
```

Using onChange

```
<DayPickerInput
   placeholder="Date Engaged"
   value={dateEngaged}
   format="dd/MM/yyyy"
   formatDate={this.formatDate}
   parseDate={this.parseDate}
   onChange={value => this.handleChangeDate(value, 'dateEngaged')}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the example from their docs on how to use handleDayChange

```
handleDayChange(selectedDay, modifiers, dayPickerInput) {
 const input = dayPickerInput.getInput();
 this.setState({
   selectedDay,
   isEmpty: !input.value.trim(),
   isValidDay: typeof selectedDay !== 'undefined',
   isDisabled: modifiers.disabled === true,
 });
}

 <DayPickerInput onDayChange={handleDayChange}/>
```